# Hide and Show Other controls inside UIView, When Expand and Collapse a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying a Expand and Collapse UIView when user click on button, I use below code to perform this operation.

```
bool isShown = true;
-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender{


    if (!isShown) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.1f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop  animations:^{
                                myView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 275, 320, 50);

                            } completion:nil];
        isShown = true;
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.1f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut  animations:^{
                                myView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 75, 320, 250);

                            } completion:nil];
        isShown = false;
    }
}
```

Problem:

When i Add Controls inside `myView` like `UILabel` and `UITextView`, those controls still showing when i collapse my view. I mean i don't want to show controls inside `myView` when i make my View Collapse and when i expand show all controls. I try to hide when i collapse but the animation doesn't look good. 
And default frame size of myView is  `myView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 275, 320, 50);`

Comment: If you want your subviews to be resized during the animation, you should set `UIViewAutoResizingMask` for your subviews.

Comment: I did `UIViewAutoResizingMask` for my subviews. But still no use, This is before collapse [IMG](http://i57.tinypic.com/1zp2zc1.png), This is after collapse [IMG](http://i57.tinypic.com/2vab2fm.png).

Comment: What is your `UIViewAutoResizingMask` exactly?

Comment: `txtView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;`

Comment: `myView.clipsToBounds = YES;` this line of code did the magic.

Comment: It will clip your subviews, your animation won't look good as you want.

Comment: so how to deal with `UIViewAutoResizingMask`

Comment: You can set all options to reduce your view completely, like:
`[label setAutoresizingMask:
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
];`
Or you can delete the ones that you don't want it to be changed.